# UPI Rest API to conduct transfers between two accounts

Tags: upi

Does the UPI system have any REST API which I can use to make a project in my computer and make a payment from one source to another? Is it even feasible for such an API to exist? And if so, what kind of authentication will it need?

If there are any existing projects, or Github repos, or ay reference, do let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these references to implement the UPI payment transfer from one source to another.  Users can conveniently use their VPA to make a secure and immediate payment without entering any bank or card details.

- Google Pay for India provides API to create a Payment Method, payment request object. Link to the Google Pay UPI integration https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/create-payment-method
- Using paytm UPI Integration: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/custom-checkout/upi/
- Paytm REST API https://developer.paytm.com/docs/api/initiate-transaction-api/?ref=payments

Comment: Thanks Sebin. I will take a look. I want to do a basic pilot project to initiate a transfer between two accounts I have one question - can this be done just over code? That is, I hit Execute in my Eclipse editor (the code will contain all necessary username/password details of the source account, it is just basic preliminary test code!), and the transfer can be initiated?

Comment: @SexyBeast, Please check this documentation https://developer.paytm.com/docs/api/initiate-transaction-api/?ref=payments , this will helps you to build your application.

Comment: Can this be done for individuals and not for buisness?