# UPI Transaction API

Tags: api, upi

Is there any API available for UPI transaction?
Example
Using my UPI ID, can i able to transfer the money to multiple UPI id?
Like if request to money transfer using API then it should be money send to a particular UPI id with zero cost.
MyUPIID->UserUPIId

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UPI Rest API to conduct transfers between two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063030/upi-rest-api-to-conduct-transfers-between-two-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a QR code using upi deeplink

Eg:
`upi://pay?pa=any@id&pn=somename&amount=10`